# In maths, what do you call the process of adjusting data points so that they can be compared?

Tags: statistics

I wanted to check that my charitable donations are spread fairly across several different countries.

To do so, I used the following formula to allow them to be compared fairly:

```
Annual Donation / Cost Of Living Index (for that country)
```

In maths, what do you call the process of adjusting data points so that they can be compared?

Comment: Not sure what you are after here.  There's certainly "scaling" or "adjusting", but each case is very specific and often controversial so the exact process needs to be spelled out in each instance.

Comment: normalization .

Comment: Why should you consider Cost of Living ? What if Country A has more Poor families than Country B ? Why not consider the amount of foreign charity already coming to Country C ? Why not multiple factors ? Point is : there is no Single Way to "Scale" or "Adjust" or "Normalize". Whichever way you **choose** , it should be **consistent & meaningful**. Some more jargon you might want to look into : "Percentages" or "Unitization" or "Parity" , which are all used in certain cases.

Comment: @Prem I simplified the scenario for the purposes of the question.

Comment: @user619894 thanks, if you answer the question, I will accept it.

Comment: I have given 3 terms, while 2 other users have given 1+2 terms, giving a total of 6 common terms, though there are many more terms not yet listed here. There is no "umbrella" term to cover all cases!